# issue with connect ecommerce system to external sales system | sql

Tags: php, mysql

Im working for integration our ecommerce system with external sales mangament system.

I need to pass orders from our website to sales system.

I prepare function for send order.

I need get sample output:

```
Array
(
    [7610] => Array
        (
            [delivery_fullname] => Wioletta Majchrzak
            [delivery_company] => 
            [delivery_address] => Bralęcin 22a
            [delivery_city] => Dolice
            [delivery_postcode] => 73-115
            [delivery_country] => Polska
            [delivery_country_code] => PL
            [invoice_fullname] => Wioletta Majchrzak
            [invoice_company] => 
            [invoice_nip] => 
            [invoice_address] => Bralęcin 22a
            [invoice_city] => Dolice
            [invoice_postcode] => 73-115
            [invoice_country] => Polska
            [invoice_country_code] => PL
            [phone] => 603991234
            [email] => wioletta.m@gmail.com
            [want_invoice] => 0
            [date_add] => 1529505947
            [user_comments] => Proszę o wysyłkę w dniu dzisiejszym
            [delivery_method] => Paczka24 - Poczta Polska
            [payment_method] => Przelew natychmiastowy
            [payment_method_cod] => 0
            [delivery_price] => 8.50
            [currency] => PLN
            [status_id] => 165751
            [paid] => 0
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22958909
                            [name] => D895 KORALIK PIES CHARMS MODUŁOWA BRANSOLETKA BEA
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [price] => 49.99
                            [tax] => 23
                            [weight] => 0
                            [sku] => D895
                            [ean] => 
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

My table structure:

table `orders`:

id
order_number
buyer_id
buyer_type
price_subtotal
price_vat
price_shipping
price_total
price_currency
coupon_code
coupon_products
coupon_discount
coupon_discount_rate
coupon_seller_id
status
payment_method
payment_status
updated_at
created_at

table `order_products`

id
order_id
seller_id
buyer_id
buyer_type
product_id
product_type
listing_type
product_title
product_slug
product_unit_price
product_quantity
product_currency
product_vat_rate
product_vat
product_total_price
variation_option_ids
commission_rate
order_status
is_approved
shipping_tracking_number
shipping_tracking_url
shipping_method
seller_shipping_cost
updated_at
created_at

table `order_shipping`:

id
order_id
shipping_first_name
shipping_last_name
shipping_email
shipping_phone_number
shipping_address
shipping_country
shipping_state
shipping_city
shipping_zip_code
billing_first_name
billing_last_name
billing_email
billing_phone_number
billing_address
billing_country
billing_state
billing_city
billing_zip_code

and here is my function:

```
function Shop_OrdersGet($request)
{
    global $options; // globalna tablica z ustawieniami
    //$dbp = $options['db_prefix']; // Data Base Prefix - prefix tabel bazy

    $response = array();

    // zapytanie pobierające zamówienia od określonego czasu
    $sql = "SELECT o.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) as time_purchased,
        FROM `orders` o
        LEFT JOIN `order_shipping` os ON os.order_id = o.id
        LEFT JOIN `order_products` op ON op.order_id = o.id
        ";

    $sql .= " WHERE o.created_at >= '{0}' AND o.id > {1}";
    $result = DB_Query($sql, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (int)$request['time_from']), (int)$request['id_from'], (int)$options['lang_id'], $options['status_paid']);

    while ($order = DB_Fetch($result))
    {
        if ($request['only_paid'] and !$order['paid'])
        {
            continue;
        }

        $o = array();

        $o['delivery_fullname'] = $order['shipping_method'];
        $o['delivery_company'] = $order['billing_first_name'];
        $o['delivery_address'] = $order['shipping_address'];
        $o['delivery_city'] = $order['shipping_city'];
        $o['delivery_state'] = $order['shipping_state'];
        $o['delivery_postcode'] = $order['shipping_zip_code'];
        $o['delivery_country'] = $order['shipping_country'];
        $o['delivery_country_code'] = $order['shipping_country'];
        $o['invoice_fullname'] = $order['billing_address'] ? $order['billing_first_name'] : $order['customers_name'];
        $o['invoice_company'] = $order['billing_street_address'] ? $order['billing_company'] : $order['customers_company'];
        $o['invoice_nip'] = $order['billing_street_address'] ? $order['billing_nip'] : $order['customers_nip'];
        $o['invoice_address'] = $order['billing_street_address'] ? $order['billing_street_address'] : $order['customers_street_address'];
        $o['invoice_city'] = $order['billing_street_address'] ? $order['billing_city'] : $order['customers_city'];
        $o['invoice_state'] = $order['billing_street_address'] ? $order['billing_state'] : $order['customers_state'];
        $o['invoice_postcode'] = $order['billing_street_address'] ? $order['billing_postcode'] : $order['customers_postcode'];
        $o['invoice_country'] = $order['billing_street_address'] ? $order['billing_country'] : $order['customers_country'];
        $o['invoice_country_code'] = $order['invoice_country_code'];
        $o['phone'] = $order['billing_phone_number'];
        $o['email'] = $order['billing_email'];
        $o['date_add'] = $order['time_purchased'];
        $o['payment_method'] = $order['payment_method'];
        $o['paid'] = $order['payment_status'];
        $o['currency'] = $order['price_currency'];
            
        // sposób wysyłki
        $sql = "SELECT shipping_method, seller_shipping_cost FROM `order_products` WHERE `order_id` = '{0}'";
        $res = DB_Query($sql, $order['order_id']);

        if ($delivery = DB_Fetch($res))
        {
            $o['delivery_method'] = substr($delivery['shipping_method'], 0, -1);
            $o['delivery_price'] = number_format($delivery['seller_shipping_cost']*$options['currency_mult'], 2, '.', '');
        }

        if ($order['shipping_module'] and preg_match('/koszt/i', $o['delivery_method']))
        {
            $o['delivery_method'] = $order['shipping_module'];
        }


        
        // produkty zamówienia
        $o['products'] = array();
        $sql = "SELECT op.*
            FROM `order_products` op
            LEFT JOIN `products` p ON p.id = op.product_id
            WHERE op.order_id = '{0}'";
        $resp = DB_Query($sql, $order['order_id']);

        while ($product = DB_Fetch($resp))
        {
            $op['id'] = $product['product_id'];
            $op['name'] = $product['product_title'];
            $op['sku'] = $product['commision_rate'];
            $op['quantity'] = $product['product_quantity'];
            $op['price'] = $product['product_total_price'];
            $op['tax'] = $product['product_vat_rate'];
            
            $o['products'][] = $op;
        }

        // zaznaczenie płatności za pobraniem
        if (preg_match('/pobran|przy odbi/i', $o['payment_method'] . $o['delivery_method']))
        {
            $o['payment_method_cod'] = 1;
        }

        $response[$order['order_id']] = $o;
    }
    
    
    return $response;
}
```

But currently I get issue:

> An error occurred while retrieving orders: SQL error: You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `orders`
> o LEFT JOIN `order_shipping` os ON os.order_id = o.id LEFT ...' at
> line 2

Can anyone check my code what is wrong?

Comment: Remove the `,` from `as time_purchased, FROM`. The comma is to separate the column names, not to mark the end of the SELECT clause. See also [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Comment: P.S. the only bit of this mountain of code which was actually relevant to the error message you posted is the SQL query itself. As per the [ask] guide, please always provide a [mre] of your issue rather than a code dump of your entire script. See also the [tour] for further guidance, as you're new. Thanks.